# Android : Editing values using alert dialog

Tags: android, popup, alert, edit

In my application I currently have an xml layout that is re-used to enter information 6 times (these are turns in a game).  This works fine.  At the end of the round I present a screen that has a summary of each turn.  I want to implement a button beside each turn to "edit" that turn.  There are 3 possible things that can be edited.  Ideally an alert dialog or something like a "popup" would be idea for this.

Would I be best off to have 3 buttons per "turn" for editing or is there a way to do this with a popup?

Thanks for your input on this matter.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16595984/1187845 this answer could help.

Comment: I did see this one but it is not quite what I need.  This will give me the alert dialog with the option of changing one value but not a potential to change 3...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could list each turn and it's information with a single edit button next to each. When the edit button is pressed, create a new activity (intent) that prompts for all three pieces of data.

Comment: This was my original way of doing it and it may be the best way of going about it.  Thanks!

Comment: If you choose to go with this way and still want a popup effect, you can use a `Dialog Theme` for your new `Activity` by modifying you `<activity>` tag.  `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"`

Comment: I will definitely look into that!  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have several options (and probably more I'm not thinking about). If these are in a `ListView` (or even if not) you could use a [ContextMenu](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu). You could have options in here to change the selected item or others. This would show a popup when the user long clicks the item

A [PopupMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html) can give you a similar effect that can pop up a list of options when the user clicks on a `Button`. Note that this requires API >= 11

You also could use an [AlertDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html), as you mentioned. But just from what little I know about what you are trying to do I'm not sure this is what you would want.

Again, I don't know enough details about what you have or want but I would say that one of the first two options would suit you best. As far as one `Button` or multiple `Button`s, that depends on the layout that will work best for your app, I suppose. You certainly could have one "Edit" `Button` which uses something like a `PopupMenu` and allows the user to choose what to edit. I hope this helped a little.